# Document Uploading Issue - Yii2

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using `\yii\web\UploadedFile` to upload a document. It works fine for less size documents. Like 200KB file, it works smoothly. But, as soon I upload 5MB file, it's not working. This was working before, but I upgraded php 5.4 to 7.2. And, after the update, it's giving such issue.

What I got is:

When I'm uploading a file approximately 200KB, `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file_name');` is returning

> Array ( [0] => yii\web\UploadedFile Object ( [name] => payment.png
> [tempName] => /tmp/phpvNIrIO [type] => image/png [size] => 234065
> [error] => 0 [_tempResource:yii\web\UploadedFile:private] => Array ( )
> ) )

And, when I'm uploading a file of 5.9MB, `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file_name');` is returning

> Array ( [0] => yii\web\UploadedFile Object ( [name] => demo.pdf
> [tempName] => [type] => [size] => 0 [error] => 1
> [_tempResource:yii\web\UploadedFile:private] => Array ( ) ) )

`tempName`, `type` is missing in this and `size` is returning as 0. Which is causing problem in uploading a document.

Even my controller function is having these settings as well.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); 
ini_set('post_max_size', '2300M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2300M');
```

Any help/hint/suggestions is appreciable.

Comment: _“Even my controller function is having these settings as well”_ - you can not set config options like `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` at runtime, and expect that to have the desired effect. Whether or not your upload request broke these limits, is determined _before_ your own custom code even runs.

Comment: please check settings in the php.ini, and if necessary change them accordingly, then restart the httpd

Comment: @CBroe, KenLee: Thank you so much. Actually, while upgrading php from 5.4 to 7.2, all php.ini settings were not applied which were modified earlier. Due to this, these problems occurred. Thank you guys, now it's fixed.

Comment: @KenLee: I've removed these settings from controller function as suggested. Now all fine. Thank You.